# Javascript custom events with wildcards (*)

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

I am making a pub/sub object for custom events and I can't figure how to add support for events like `user.logged.*` where it would subscribe the subscriber to the events `user.logged.in` and `user.logged.out`

Are there any resources cause Google can't help.

**EDIT**

Maybe in my subscribe function i should check the passed event type for wildcards and subscribe to both events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would constraint it to just the last part be a wildcard. Then, `trigger` would look like

```
function trigger(name, data) {
    var parts = name.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        call_subscribers(parts.slice(0, i).join('.'), data, parts.slice(i+1));
    }
}

function call_subscribers(event_name, data, remaining_event_parts) {
    for(var subscriberIndex in subscribers[event_name]) {
        subscribers[subscriberIndex](data, remaining_event_parts);
    }
}
```

On this examble, you would do

```
subscribers = [];
subscribers['user.logged'] = [
    function(data) { // here, we dont care about the remaining parts
        // do what you have to do
    }
];
trigger('user.logged.in'); // calls 'user', 
                          //'user.logged' (the wildcard we want) and 
                          // 'user.logged.in'
```

Then, you could register the events `user`, `user.logged` and `user.logged.in`. And would effectively get a event hierarchy. With the rest of the event passed to the handler you could maybe do fun things too...

Comment: Could you explain the 3 parameters of the call_subscribers()? If the name is "user.logged.*" how will it register "user.logged.in"?

Comment: Updated, first is the name of the event being triggered, second the data passed in from outside and last part is the remaining parts of the actually called event's name.

Comment: where toggle you mean trigger?

Comment: if I pass trigger('user.logged.*') is it going to register '*' as an event type?

Comment: yes, but what sense would it do if we would trigger logged.in and logged.out the same time? Wanted you to be able to trigger both events the same time? I understood that you wanted to trigger another function if any of the events happen?

Comment: @chchrist let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1839/discussion-between-marc-and-chchrist)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your list of events in some sort of collection like this:

```
var events = ["user.logged.in", 
              "user.logged.out", 
              "user.disconnect", 
              "system.disconnect"
              // etc etc etc
             ];
```

Then, when an entity subscribes with "user.logged.*", you could do a comparison of the parts like this:

```
function subscribe(evt) {
    var evtParts = evt.split("."),
        eventParts, eventIdx, ii, subscribeTo = [];

    for (eventIdx = 0; eventIdx < events.length; eventIdx += 1) {
        eventParts = events[eventIdx].split(".");

        for (ii = 0; ii < eventParts.length && ii < evtParts.length; ii += 1) {
            if (evtParts[ii] == "*") {
                subscribeTo.push(events[eventIdx]);
            }
            else if (eventParts[ii] == evtParts[ii] && ii == evtParts.length - 1) {
                subscribeTo.push(events[eventIdx]);
            }
            else if (eventParts[ii] != evtParts[ii]) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now, subscribeTo contains all the events that match evt, 
    // even when evt contains a wildcard.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you might take a look at EventEmitter2: https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2

```
server.on('foo.*', function(value1, value2) {
  console.log(this.event, value1, value2);
});
```